# Based on button click modal dialog and jquery ajax calls

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

[image]

**Html Code**: for Add New button

```
<div>
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#addnewDepartment" id="add-new-department-btn">Add New</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#addnewVehicle" id="add-new-vehicle-btn"> Add New </a>
</div>
```

**Modal Dialog** frames:

```
    <!-- Adding New Department -->

<div class="modal fade" id="addnewDepartment">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form:form id="add-new-department" action="add-new-department" method="POST" commandName="department">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Add New Department</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label path="departmentname" >Department</form:label>
                    <form:input required="true" path="departmentname" class="form-control" />
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div id="department_status">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input data-bb-handler="confirm" type="submit" value="Add">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
    </div>
    </form:form>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>



     <!-- Adding New Vehicle Type -->



            <div class="modal fade" id="addnewVehicle">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form:form id="add-new-typeofvehicle" action="add-new-typeofvehicle" method="POST"
                            commandName="vehicle">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Vehicle Type</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <form:label path="vehicletype" class="col-md-5 control-label">Vehicle Type</form:label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <form:input path="vehicletype" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <div id="vehicle_status">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input data-bb-handler="confirm" type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                    data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </form:form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
```

**Jquery Ajax Call with validation**:

```
$("#add-new-department").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules : {
            departmentname : {
                required : true,
                alphanumericsd : true
            },

        },

        submitHandler : function(form) {

                var departmentname = $('#departmentname').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : $("#add-new-department").attr("action"),
                    type : "POST",
                    data : "departmentname="+departmentname,

                    success : function(response) {
                        if($.isEmptyObject(response)) { 
                            $('#department_status').html('Sorry! Duplicate Record!').css('color','red').show().fadeOut(5000);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#department_status').html('New Dapartment Added Successfully').css('color','green').show().fadeOut(5000);
                            $('#departmentname').val('');
                            $('#department').append(new Option(response.departmentname,response.departmentid));
                        }

                    },  
                 error : function(e) {  
                  alert('Error: ' + e.responseText);   
                 } 
                });
        }
    });

    // Setup form validation on the #add-new-typeofvehicle element
    $("#add-new-typeofvehicle").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules : {
            vehicletype : {
                required : true,
                alphanumericsd : true
            },

        },

        submitHandler : function(form) {
            var vehicletype = $('#vehicletype').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : $("#add-new-typeofvehicle").attr("action"),
                    type : "POST",
                    data : "vehicletype="+vehicletype,

                    success : function(response) {
                        if($.isEmptyObject(response)) { 
                            $('#vehicle_status').html('Sorry! Duplicate Record!').css('color','red').show().fadeOut(5000);
                        }
                        else {
                        $('#vehicle_status').html('New Vehicle Type Added Successfully').css('color','green').show().fadeOut(5000);
                        $('#vehicletype').val('');
                        $('#typeofvehicle').append(new Option(response.vehicletype,response.vehicleid));
                        }
                    },  
                 error : function(e) {  
                  alert('Error: ' + e);   
                 } 
                });
        }
    });
```

I want to minimize my code because i have so many add new options in my project

So, please any one suggest me how to write only single code for modal dialog and one jquery ajax call as more general

Comment: you can write a plugin, here's a good topic on how to write a basic plugin: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/

Answer (score 1):

By making some change in your html ..you can make universal jquery execution

1. place the class onform tag 'validate'
2. change department status tag as  `<div id="department_status" class="status">&nbsp;</div>`
3. you need to validation rul on html tag like  `<form:input required="true"  path="departmentname" class="form-control alphanumericsd" />`

   $('form.validate').each(function(){
                       $(this).validate({
                           submitHandler : function(form) {
                               strval = ''
                                   $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
                                       if(strval == '')
                                       strval = $(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val();
                                       else
                                       strval = ','+$(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val();
                                       })

   ```
                               $.ajax({
                                   url : $(this).attr("action"),
                                   type : "POST",
                                   data :strval,

                                   success : function(response) {
                                       if($.isEmptyObject(response)) { 
                                           $('.status',this).html('Sorry! Duplicate Record!').css('color','red').show().fadeOut(5000);
                                       }
                                       else {
                                           $('.status',this).html('New Dapartment Added Successfully').css('color','green').show().fadeOut(5000);
                                           $('input[type=text]').val('');
                                           //$('#department').append(new Option(response.departmentname,response.departmentid));
                                       }

                                   },  
                                error : function(e) {  
                                 alert('Error: ' + e.responseText);   
                                } 
                               });
                       }
                   });

               })
   ```